# sklearn decision tree random state parameter in spark mllib decision tree

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, apache-spark-mllib

I had a sklearn decision tree and I knew that with different values of random state parameter, the result may change. But now I have to use spark mllib instead of sklearn. Is there any parameters in spark mllib decision tree that work in the same way as sklearn random state ?